Hpux and TCB, how to enable login console?
I'm on hpux 10.20 (for testing), is TCB-enabled
when I try a login from a serial console this m
essage appear
GenericSysName [HP Release B.10.20] (see /etc/issue)
login: root
Cannot obtain database information on this terminal

Disabling tcb (sic!) works
The question is: how to enable the tty login using tcb?
Thanks

It's been a long time since I worked on a HP-UX with Trusted System Mode in effect, but I think the error message might indicate that either /tcb/files/auth/devassign or /tcb/files/ttys might be damaged or incomplete.
See man 4 devassign and man 4 ttys for more details, and man 4 authcap for general information on the file format used for both files.

Solution found.
I have to edit the file
/tcb/files/ttys

and add this line
tty0p0:t_devname=tty0p0:t_uid=root:t_logtime#1731919530:\
        :t_unsuctime#1731919221:t_maxtries#777:chkent:

I have check the database with
authck -t

Now works fine

Looks like you found it yourself just as I was writing my answer. Feel free to accept your own answer.
